# php Curl iterate through json decoded array

Tags: php

I have a problem with a json decoded array using cURL. I am gathering data from Leadfeeder to get recent companies that visited our site. I have a custom start and end date and I wish to return all the companies that visited in the day. I can do this but it returns a json array. I am only able to access one company. However I need to access the entire array

below is an example of the code

```
$url =  "https://api.leadfeeder.com/accounts/youraccount/visits?start_date=".date("2018-02-04")."&end_date=".date("Y-m-d").""; // Captcha plugin url



$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Authorization: Token token=Token-here'));   
$result = (string)curl_exec($ch);

echo "<pre>";    
$leadfeeder = json_decode($result, true); 


@$lead_id = $leadfeeder['data'][1]['attributes']['lead_id'];

 foreach ($leadfeeder as $r) {
     echo $r['data'];
 }
```

When I run the above I get the following error

> Notice:  Undefined index: data in /opt/lampp/htdocs/leadfeeder.php on 
>       line 28
>   Notice:  Undefined index: data in /opt/lampp/htdocs/leadfeeder.php on 
>       line 28

This is an example of the output

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 86b8e468-0af7-11e8-8738-11129da81150
                    [type] => visits
                    [attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [source] => en.wikipedia.org
                            [medium] => referral
                            [referring_url] => 
                            [page_depth] => 1
                            [visit_route] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [hostname] =>
                                            [page_path] => /
                                            [previous_page_path] => (entrance)
                                            [time_on_page] => 0
                                            [page_title] => 
                                            [page_url] => 
                                            [display_page_name] => 
                                        )

                                )

                            [keyword] => 
                            [visit_length] => 0
                            [started_at] => 2018-02-05T23:51:00.000Z
                            [date] => 2018-02-05
                            [hour] => 23
                            [lead_id] => 02e01b12-2c9b-11e5-b645-3df00765f195_uM2sktjSDJNrnkRHg49WRe
                        )

                )
```

Comment: If I understood your output example correctly, you only have one `$leadfeeder['data']`, so you should probably change `foreach ($leadfeeder as $r) {` to `foreach ($leadfeeder['data'] as $r) {` or something like that.

Comment: ...plus you probably shouldn't try and echo an array.

Comment: how does the whole structure look like? Please add the results model from this API to your question or dump the whole array (e.g. var_dump() or var_export())